# default plot for mob object (glm tree) not returned; using party package

Tags: generalized-linear-model, cart, partitioning, party, recursive-model

I'm trying to plot a glm tree using the package `party`. Per the [reference guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf), the default plot of the terminal node *should be* a spinogram as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqdJz.png) but I am only getting [scatterplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5YVx.png) at the final node. Dataset is [here](https://github.com/CaitLittlef/fia-regen/blob/master/data.pipo.short.csv).

```
tree.mob <- mob(regen_pipo ~ YEAR.DIFF
                | YEAR.DIFF + BALive_pipo + BALiveTot
                + def59_z_03 + def68_z_03
                + CMD_1995 + MAP_1995
                + FIRE.SEV,
                data = data.pipo,
                model = glinearModel, family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                control = mob_control(minsplit = 50))
plot(tree.mob)
```

Even this doesn't generate the spinogram -- which I think should explicitly enforce it.

```
plot(tree.mob, terminal_panel=node_bivplot(tree.mob, cdplot = FALSE))
```

I'd appreciate any guidance!

Comment: Hello! I understand that this question may be more appropriate for Stack Overflow (as @AchimZeileis helped me to understand in his exceptionally helpful response). Is there a way for me to transfer the question to that forum? Or is it destined to languish, closed, here on Cross Validated? Thanks for your patience with a new user!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the site! A couple of comments first:

- Your question is a bit borderline for CrossValidated because it is not so much about the statistics but more about the software. Hence, StackOverflow (with [r] and [party] tags) would probably have been more appropriate.
- The question does have a statistical background, though, namely that the distinction between categorical variables (coded as factors in R) and numerical variables plays an important role for the `ctree()` and `mob()` algorithms in `party`/`partykit`. (In other tree algorithms such as CART/`rpart` it does not as much.)
- The `partykit` package is now preferred over the older `party` package. The problem you describe occurs equally in both versions, though. However, `glmtree()` has a nicer interface than the old `mob()`.

Now for the answer itself. The decision which plot to choose in a visualization is made based on the classes of the dependent variable and the regressor variable(s). In this case `regen_pipo` and `YEAR.DIFF` are both numeric, hence a scatter plot is employed. But, of course, `regen_pipo` is conceptually a binary categorical variable and would thus be better coded as a factor. Similarly, `FIRE.SEV` should probably be an ordered factor. Then `mob()` would have taken a different (and more appropriate) parameter stability test to assess whether the model should be split in `FIRE.SEV`.

Combining all comments above, I would have used the following code. (I wasn't sure what 0/1 stand for in `regen_pipo`, better factor labels would be nice in the spinograms.) Data:

```
data.pipo <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CaitLittlef/fia-regen/master/data.pipo.short.csv")
data.pipo <- transform(data.pipo,
  regen_pipo = factor(regen_pipo),
  FIRE.SEV = factor(FIRE.SEV, ordered = TRUE)
)
```

Model-based tree:

```
library("partykit")
tree.mob <- glmtree(regen_pipo ~ YEAR.DIFF | I(YEAR.DIFF) + BALive_pipo + BALiveTot + CMD_1995 + MAP_1995 + FIRE.SEV,
  data = data.pipo, family = binomial(link = "logit"), minsplit = 50)
plot(tree.mob)
```

[image: glmtree]

Notes:

- The variables `def59_z_03` and `def68_z_03` from your question were not part of the CSV and are hence omitted in my example.
- It is fine to use `YEAR.DIFF` as both regressor and partitioning variable. However, some defaults (such as the right plot) have an easier time if there are two separate columns in the model frame. Hence, I used `I(YEAR.DIFF)` as the partitioning variable. Yields the same tree but different default plot.